# A Conway quadratic (form) equation in four variables

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, integer-lattices

In the [Sensual Quadratic Form](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883850303) page 44, J.H. Conway is discussing isospectral lattices of dimension 4 when he states the following:

> ''... we find all solutions of the equation(s) $x^2+7y^2+13z^2+19w^2=48$ ... to find possible vectors of norm 4 ... in $L^+(1,7,13,19)$ and $L^-(1,7,13,19)$.''

Here $L^+$ and $L^-$ are the isospectral lattices in question. I know that 'all solutions' in this case refers to integer solutions, but I wonder how one goes about finding these. The statement is written in such a way that it would seem easy to do, yet I have no idea where to start.

Comment: positive definite. For $x^2 + 7y^2 + 13 z^2 + 19 w^2 < 100$ we have $|x|<10,$ $|y| \leq 3, $ $|z| \leq 2, $  $|w| \leq 2.$  Finite search if you wish to use a computer to do it.

Comment: 48       1   2   0   1;
  48       3   1   1   1;
  48       4   0   1   1;
  96       0   1   1   2;
  96       1   3   1   1;
  96       4   2   2   0;
  96       5   0   2   1;
  96       6   2   1   1;
  96       7   2   0   1;
  96       8   0   1   1;

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you! The inequalities for the variables are sort of worst case scenarios for each, given that their combination is less than 100. I would gladly accept your comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to find all solutions with $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ nonnegative. Because the quadratic form is positive definite, we see that
$$y^2\leq\frac{48}{7},\qquad z^2\leq\frac{48}{13},\qquad w^2\leq\frac{48}{19},$$
and so $y\leq2$, $z\leq1$, $w\leq1$, and for each choice of $(y,z,w)$ there is at most one (nonnegative) value of $x$ that satisfies the equation. So this leaves just $12$ cases to check, which isn't too much work to do by hand even.

Comment: I think you are missing absolute values in your inequalities for y,z etc

Comment: I've restricted to nonnegative values, as that leaves fewer cases to check.

Comment: Ah, I was being careless. Excuse me!